# Integrating Passport with my Angular App: How to start authentication flow from client-side?

Tags: angularjs, node.js, passport.js, passport-facebook, passport-twitter

I am new to AngularJS and NodeJS.

I am using passport-facebook and passport-twitter for a project. Everything is set up properly on the server; getting the access token needed to make API calls.

But I do not know how to integrate it with my AngularJS app.

FBGraph is being used to make API calls, while passport-facebook was supposed to help me get the access token; but I cannot obviously use

```
$http.get(constant.BASEURL + "login/twitter");
```

which is the route that starts the authentication flow. It is working fine when the route is written directly into the address bar.

QUESTION: How can I start the authentication flow (pop up/redirect to permission page of Facebook/Twitter) from my Angular app?

As a temporary solution, I used Satellizer from client to get the access token, but it does not support Pinterest and Tumblr it seems.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Had to use `$window.location.href = url` to start the authentication flow rather than `$http.get(url)`; the callbackUrl returned control to my application.